# Greenplum table definition does not show detailed child tables/partitions & distribution key

Tags: psql, database-partitioning, greenplum

```
\d+ {table_name}
```

is not showing detailed partition & distribution key information.

I guess there might be some configuration parameter has not been set as previously it was showing perfect.

By default it was previously showing all child tables / distribution key of that table/etc.

Comment: please, attach the output you see for "\d" and "\d+" for a specific table

Answer (score 0):

if \d+ does shows you, the distribution key; then, you can use below mentioned query to display distribution key.

select * from gp_distribution_policy where localoid=(select oid from pg_class where relname='My_table_name');

Comment: My problem is I know table is partitioned and well distributed however \d+ doesn't show all child partitions, indexes etc...

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have two tables named the same thing with one in the public schema and one in different schema.  When you don't specify the schema name, Greenplum, like PostgreSQL, will search for the table name in the schemas listed in your search path.  The first match, based on the order of your search_path, will be displayed.

Notice how I didn't specify the schema name and just "\d store_sales" but the table listed is "public.store_sales"?  It was determined by my search_path.

```
    gpdb=# \d store_sales
                Table "public.store_sales"
            Column         |     Type     | Modifiers 
    -----------------------+--------------+-----------
     ss_sold_date_sk       | integer      | 
     ss_sold_time_sk       | integer      | 
     ss_item_sk            | integer      | not null
     ss_customer_sk        | integer      | 
     ss_cdemo_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_hdemo_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_addr_sk            | integer      | 
     ss_store_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_promo_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_ticket_number      | integer      | not null
     ss_quantity           | integer      | 
     ss_wholesale_cost     | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_list_price         | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_sales_price        | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_discount_amt   | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_sales_price    | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_wholesale_cost | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_list_price     | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_tax            | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_coupon_amt         | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_net_paid           | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_net_paid_inc_tax   | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_net_profit         | numeric(7,2) | 
    Distributed by: (ss_item_sk)
```

I also have this same table name in the tpcds schema which is partitioned.  When I specify the schema name, I find the right table that is partitioned.

```
    gpdb=# \d tpcds.store_sales
      Append-Only Columnar Table "tpcds.store_sales"
            Column         |     Type     | Modifiers 
    -----------------------+--------------+-----------
     ss_sold_date_sk       | integer      | 
     ss_sold_time_sk       | integer      | 
     ss_item_sk            | integer      | not null
     ss_customer_sk        | integer      | 
     ss_cdemo_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_hdemo_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_addr_sk            | integer      | 
     ss_store_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_promo_sk           | integer      | 
     ss_ticket_number      | integer      | not null
     ss_quantity           | integer      | 
     ss_wholesale_cost     | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_list_price         | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_sales_price        | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_discount_amt   | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_sales_price    | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_wholesale_cost | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_list_price     | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_ext_tax            | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_coupon_amt         | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_net_paid           | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_net_paid_inc_tax   | numeric(7,2) | 
     ss_net_profit         | numeric(7,2) | 
    Checksum: t
    Number of child tables: 7 (Use \d+ to list them.)
    Distributed by: (ss_item_sk)
```

Using \d+ shows the partitions.

```
    gpdb=# \d+ tpcds.store_sales
                                            Append-Only Columnar Table "tpcds.store_sales"
            Column         |     Type     | Modifiers | Storage | Compression Type | Compression Level | Block Size | Description 
    -----------------------+--------------+-----------+---------+------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------
     ss_sold_date_sk       | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_sold_time_sk       | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_item_sk            | integer      | not null  | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_customer_sk        | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_cdemo_sk           | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_hdemo_sk           | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_addr_sk            | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_store_sk           | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_promo_sk           | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_ticket_number      | integer      | not null  | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_quantity           | integer      |           | plain   | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_wholesale_cost     | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_list_price         | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_sales_price        | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_ext_discount_amt   | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_ext_sales_price    | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_ext_wholesale_cost | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_ext_list_price     | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_ext_tax            | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_coupon_amt         | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_net_paid           | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_net_paid_inc_tax   | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
     ss_net_profit         | numeric(7,2) |           | main    | none             | 0                 | 32768      | 
    Checksum: t
    Child tables: store_sales_1_prt_no_date_set,
                  store_sales_1_prt_y_1998,
                  store_sales_1_prt_y_1999,
                  store_sales_1_prt_y_2000,
                  store_sales_1_prt_y_2001,
                  store_sales_1_prt_y_2002,
                  store_sales_1_prt_y_2003
    Has OIDs: no
    Options: appendonly=true, orientation=column
    Distributed by: (ss_item_sk)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know whats wrong here

If you check DDL or take a dump of any table (using pg_dump) from other server (not directly GP cluster) where client is install and connection granted to GP server, Generated DDL by \d, \d+ or by pg_dump, you will not get distribution class 
I just tried for partition tables also, partition class will also be missing.

Same time if you try \d, \d+ or pg_dump from psql prompt @ GP Master server
you will get both distribution and partition class in generated DDL of table

You can also try to generate external table's DDL
from ETL server or any other server where GP  client is install, from this psql prompt you will not get  Location class.

Try this and revert

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using psql offered by greenplum, no "greenplum feature" will be displayed. Please check if you are using the right psql.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer as it need a confirmation and not directly solve the problem. Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)